# Mutli LiveData objects for multi view types in RecycleView

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I have one question about RecyclerView Adapter. My list need multi view types matching with multi objects in ViewModel.

The first, I have ViewModel like this:

```
class MyViewModel...{
    val a = MutableLiveData<A>()
    val b = MutableLiveData<B>()
    val c = MutableLiveData<C>()
    ...
}
```

Each variables in MyViewModel will be handle by observer inside my activity:

```
class MyActivity... {
    ...
    fun observerSettings() {
        viewMd.a.observer(this, Observer {
            myadapter.setA(it)
        })
        viewMd.b.observer(this, Observer {
            myadapter.setB(it)
        })
        viewMd.c.observer(this, Observer {
            myadapter.setC(it)
        })
    }
}
```

To apply data changed in adapter:

```
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private var a: A? = null
    private var b: B? = null
    private var c: C? = null

    fun setA(a: A) {
        this.a = a
        notifyItemChanged(0)
    }

    fun setB(b: B) {
        this.b = b
        notifyItemChanged(1)
    }

    fun setC(c: C) {
        this.c = c
        notifyItemChanged(2)
    }

    ....

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        when (viewType) {
            "A" -> MyViewHolderA.create(parent)
            "B" -> MyViewHolderB.create(parent)
            "C" -> MyViewHolderC.create(parent)
            else -> ...
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder.itemViewType) {
            "A" -> (holder as A).bind(a)
            "B" -> (holder as B).bind(b)
            "C" -> (holder as C).bind(c)
        }
    }
}
```

It's seem to be not cleary and clean code. But I dont find any solution to make it more clear and clean. 
My question about the variables a, b and c from MyViewModel need to notifyItemChanged and store model objects inside both adapter and view model in my code.

Have any ideal to cleary and more clean here? 
Thank so much for your time^^

Comment: Not enough details..., you net to show 3 different rows or 3 different types of lists?

Comment: @ShlomiFresko Exact. Three types that's mean three defference layout and three object model